# junit -- verify LOGGER without mocking

Tags: logging, junit, mocking, mockito, verify

In my functional test, I do not want to mock LOGGER object but want to verify it in erroneous scenarios. Below are few lines of code :

```
private static final Logger LOGGER_OF_ANOTHER_CLASS = Logger.getLogger(DataProvider.class);

@Before public void setup() { Mockito.spy(LOGGER_OF_ANOTHER_CLASS); }

@Test public void testWarningIsLoggedWhenNoDataExists() {
    whenInvalidCriteriaIsPassed();    // This is private method 
    Mockito.verify(LOGGER_OF_ANOTHER_CLASS, times(1)).warn(new ArgumentMatcher<String>() {
        @Override
        public boolean matches(Object argument) {
            String message = (String) argument;
            return message.startsWith("Unable to fetch data for criteria:");
        }
    });
}
```

On this I am getting exception

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: 
Argument passed to verify() is not a mock!
Examples of correct verifications:
verify(mock).someMethod();
verify(mock, times(10)).someMethod();
verify(mock, atLeastOnce()).someMethod();
```

I tried few scenarios searching on StackOverflow but failed.

Answer (score 0):

I think exception is spot on. A small change will probably fix your test issue.

`private static final Logger LOGGER_OF_ANOTHER_CLASS = Mockito.spy(Logger.getLogger(DataProvider.class));`